# "mysql join with not equal to operator " not working

Tags: mysql

first attempt

```
SELECT s.name,s.email,s.student_id,a.hostel_id,s.image,s.course_id,s.year, s.address
FROM sys_student_account s, sys_room_allotment a
WHERE s.student_id!=a.student_id AND s.name like 'SAMS%'
GROUP BY s.student_id ORDER BY s.name LIMIT 0,20
```

second attempt

```
SELECT s.name,s.email,s.student_id,a.hostel_id,s.image,s.course_id,s.year, s.address
FROM sys_student_account s, sys_room_allotment a
WHERE NOT(s.student_id=a.student_id) AND s.name like 'SAMS%'
GROUP BY s.student_id ORDER BY s.name LIMIT 0,20
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: no no i am not getting error.i just want to get info of student from student account table which are not existing in room allotment table, but the query not working properly

Comment: Then edit the question to explain what you want, and what you get instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand joins properly. Your code gives entirely different result than what you want.

use following code snippet:

```
from sys_student_account s
left join sys_room_allotment a on ( s.student_id=a.student_id)

where a.student_id is NULL and s.name like 'SAMS%'
```

Note: check whether you need `group by` clause and implement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A join, be it an implicit or explicit join creates a Cartesian product between both tables - that it, it pairs every row from the first table with every row from the other table. This result is narrowed down by the join condition which should ensure that these matches are done according to some logic according to your schema. In this case, you are attempting to join a row in `sys_student_account` with every row in `sys_room_allotment` that has a different `student_id` - which isn't really what you're trying to achieve. A much simpler approach may be to use the `exists` operator instead of a join:

```
SELECT   s.* -- or any other fields from sys_student_account
FROM     sys_student_account s 
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   sys_room_allotment a
                     WHERE  s.student_id = a.student_id)
ORDER BY s.name
```